# Утановить пакет python-ldap3

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, package, apt-get

Есть сервер Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Требуется, чтобы на нем была библиотека python-ldap3. Однако в репозитории для версии 14.04 такого пакета нет. Усложняется все тем, что сервер ограничен в интернете: есть доступ только к официальному репозиторию.

Пробовал установить из исходников

```
python setup.py install
```

но, судя по всему, во время установки он пытается докачать что-то. А так как интернет ограничен, ничего не выходит.

Как можно выйти из ситуации и установить требуемый пакет?

Comment: может быть, пакета python-ldap будет достаточно?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Пытаюсь установить вот это дополнение http://multicorn.org/foreign-data-wrappers/#idldap-foreign-data-wrapper . В требованиях четко сказано что нужен ldap3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если по каким-то причинам не подходит пакет `python-ldap`, [присутствующий](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-ldap) в репозитории для *ubuntu 14.04*, то можно скачать файл с пакетом с любого из зеркал, например, с [яндекса](http://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-ldap3/python-ldap3_0.9.4.2-1_all.deb), и установить с помощью программы `dpkg`:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /путь/к/файлу.deb
```

судя по [списку зависимостей](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/python-ldap3) пакета, проблем быть не должно, если уже установлены дистрибутивные пакеты `python` и `python-pyasn1`.

Comment: Спасибо! python-ldap действительно не подходит, а ваш вариант я сейчас попропбую.